# Swipe based html5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm in a research stage for the html5 canvas game I'd like to build as a side project to improve my skills in the area. Surprisingly after some research on the internet I was not able to find any good articles/tutorials on how to make swipe based games. Idea is simple, user can swipe right, left and down of the screen, and based on what they swipe and where they swipe it game awards points. Could you provide any suggestions and resources that could be used for such project and help kickstart the development. Are there any particular keywords that I should look up that would help in gathering information?

Comment: https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/hammer.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for responding to touch and swipe events.